# Error with expected identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c

I have a curly bracket up at the top before my autorelease pool and for some reason it is being listed with an error expected identifier or '('.  i'm not sure what this means and i've been struggling to fix it, i am a computer science major who is trying to teach myself some objective C from steve kochan's book before starting my classes.  Any help would be great!  Thank you!(The code is posted below)

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]);
{  

    autoreleasepool; 
    {
        Fraction *myFraction;

        //Create an instance of a Fraction

        myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
        myFraction = [myFraction init];

        // Set fraction to 1/3

        [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
        [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

        // Display the fraction using the print method
        NSLog (" The value of myFraction is:");
        [myFraction print];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed one character.

Try `@autoreleasepool {` there.

(add a @ and remove the semicolon)

Answer (score 3):

Rethink where you post your semicolons

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]); {
```

should be

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
```

and

```
autoreleasepool;
```

should be

```
@autoreleasepool
```

Comment: It was that stupid semi colon!  I didn't think it should be there but i was just trying things at that point, i knew the @ should be there i fixed that.  Thank you so much!  I've been stumped for a while!

Comment: You are welcome :). But if this answered your question: please mark this answer as "accepted answer" using the tick on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
NSLog (" The value of myFraction is:");
```

should be

```
NSLog (@" The value of myFraction is:");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    @autoreleasepool {
        Fraction *myFraction;

        //Create an instance of a Fraction
        myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        // Set fraction to 1/3
        [myFraction setNumerator:1];
        [myFraction setDenominator:3];

        // Display the fraction using the print method
        NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is:");
        [myFraction print];

        [myFraction release]; // you will read about this later in your book ;)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't have to release the object anymore since they added ARC haha